# How to create a file from the Mac OS terminal and open it in sublime?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How to create a file from the Mac OS terminal and open it in sublime? But not in a new sublime window, but in a new tab, in an already open sublime?
**Example:**

```
touch filename.js -a 'Sublime Text' $_
```

Is there any flag or argument that can be added here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do (assuming you have the `subl` helper script in your `$PATH`) is type `subl filename.ext` and Sublime Text will open it in the currently-active window. You don't need to call `touch` at all.

Note: this will work on any OS.